# Amazon RDS: OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'verus-db.ck3ge4zvxdmt.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)")

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I keep getting the following error message

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'verus-db.ck3ge4zvxdmt.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com ' (timed out)")
```

I used the following code

```
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='verus-db.ck3ge4zvxdmt.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
                         user='admin',
                         password='my-password-is-not-here',
                         db='verus_ai_db')

# create cursor
cursor=connection.cursor()
```

Do not worry that is not my real password :)

Here is a picture of my security

[image]

Comment: MySQL != Microsoft SQL Server. Did you mean to tag `sql-server`?

Comment: By default mysql uses TCP traffic over port 3306 (at least according to https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/mysql-port/ ) so if you're trying to connect from outside the security group that the RDS instance is in, you should probably allow that traffic.

Comment: According to the SG, the traffic is open to all ports. So, the questio now is. Is it in private subnet and from where are you trying to access it?